# Best approach to minimize data loss when converting raster from projected to geographic coordinate system

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, rgdal

I have a worldwide raster file in PCS roughly at 1° resolution (extent is is 90 to -60 degrees latitude and 180 to -180 longitude) that I want to convert to GCS at 2° resolution but the current method that I use leads to data distortion. The origin raster contains categorical values but the same question would apply for continuous values. I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

```
#create raster in PCS - CEA projection
x <- raster(ncol=360, nrow=142, xmn=-17367529, xmx=17367529, ymn=-6356742, ymx=7348382)
projection(x) <- "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
values(x)=runif(51120, 1, 99)
# my target raster format
y <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=75, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-60, ymx=90)
projection(y) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
values(y)=runif(13500, 1, 99)
#downscale to match my target raster resolution
x2deg=raster::aggregate(x,fact=2)
#when I try to project I get the first error
x2deg.gcs = projectRaster(x2deg, y)
```

> Error in if (maxy == miny) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> In addition: Warning message:
> In rgdal::rawTransform(projfrom, projto, nrow(xy), xy[, 1], xy[,  :
> 48 projected point(s) not finite

```
#So I slightly cut the extent and get the desired result
extent(x2deg) <- c(xmin= -17367529, xmax= 17367529, ymin= 0.999*(-6356742), ymax= .999*(7348382))
x2deg.gcs = projectRaster(x2deg, y)
```

Should I perhaps downscale ncol and nrows in raster `x` using a different factor? I know I will have to do some uneven interpolation to go from 142 rows to 75 but for example `aggregate` doesn't take fractions in the argument `frac`. Maybe there is another package that handles this better such as rgdal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works better with `terra`

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(ncol=360, nrow=142, xmin=-17367529, xmax=17367529, ymin=-6356742, ymax=7348382)
crs(x) <- "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
values(x) <- 1:ncell(x)

y <- rast(ncol=180, nrow=75, xmin=-180, xmax=180, ymin=-60, ymax=90)
crs(y) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

p <- project(x, y)
```

Comment: And here comes prof. Hijmans and solves my problem in a few seconds after I spent hours on it! :-). Good to know about this new package! Just a question, I am noticing slightly different results if I first do x=aggregate(x,fact=2). Is this advisable or should I let project() handle all the conversion?

Comment: I agree with the idea of aggregating. That is what `raster` does. In `terra` the GDAL warp algorithm is used behind the scenes and I have not experimented enough with it to know if it matters, and how that depends on the method used (near, blinear)